# Green's Function in some problems (2-D) causes the occurrence of ln(0) at $G(x=x_0,y = y_0)$. How does one get around this?

Tags: computational-mathematics, greens-function

[From the document I found here](https://dept.math.lsa.umich.edu/%7Esijue/greensfunction.pdf) (and many others which cover this exact same problem as well), we have the following where I added some edits to help follow along:

[image]

So I went ahead and tested the Dirichlet BCs case for different points $(x_0,y_0)$ for Green's Function, and I do in fact get an error at the point where $x=x_0$ and $y=y_0$. Basically:
$$\lim_{x_0\rightarrow x,y_0\rightarrow y} G(x_0,y_0) = -\infty$$
This problem looks familiar from my classes in calculus having to do with natural logs and derivatives at 0, but I don't know if that's what I'm looking for. Any advice?

Comment: Look carefully at the definition of Green’s functions. They are never defined on the diagonal $\mathbf x=\mathbf x_0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin By "diagonal", are you referring to the distance | **x**-**x**_0|? Sorry I'm not familiar with the terminology. As for the "definition", I'm assuming you mean 0.5 (inside the linked pdf) and 0.13? Or the equations for G(**x**,**x**_0)?

Comment: In $X\times X$, the set of points $(x,y)$ with $y=x$ is called the diagonal. The Green's function $G(\mathbf x,\mathbf y)$ is never defined when $\mathbf x=\mathbf y$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Makes sense! So would it follow that it is impossible to find the solution (from Green's second identity) $u(x,y) = \int_C f(x_0) \nabla G \cdot \hat{n} dx_o$ in the case of picking a point (x,y) where $x = y$ since G cannot be defined there?

Comment: That makes no sense. Read your text more carefully.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're getting at. But I do recall that performing the derivatives via the gradient operator does make the natural log function go away so we no longer have to worry about the original issue I was putting forth. Anyways, what I was getting at was I didn't know if you could obtain the derivative of a function at a point where that function is undefined. I was not asking a question rhetorically, but out of curiosity as I did not know. I guess that's not always the case like say for this problem.

Comment: I'm referring to formula (0.3), which is how you apply the Green's function to solve the PDE. You're confusing the double set of coordinates for the Green's function with the *single* set of coordinates $(x,y)$ on the plane. There is no problem with $x=y$ there.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you for getting back to me (and also commenting on my other post), I will look this over and try to get back to you tomorrow!

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm aware that there is no problem at the point(s) x=y. I'm talking about the equation for G(**x**,**x_0**) = $\frac{1}{4\pi} \ln(\frac{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2}{(x-x_0)^2+(y+y_0)^2})$ where you said this isn't an issue bc they are never defined at **x**=**x_0**. I'm not great with this notation, but I think that is to say that simultaneously, we cannot have both $x=x_0$ and $y = y_0$ simultaneously. Additionally, I found some other limitations from 0.5.

Comment: @TedShifrin  According to 0.5, to satisfy the homogeneous BCs, G(**x**,**x**_0) = 0 on C (the boundaries), then for x = 0 or L, $y_0$ must be 0. For y = 0, x can be anything. For y=L, x can be anything, but $y_0$ must be 0. And as for $x=x_0$ and $y=y_0$, G can be defined only if one or the other is true, not both at once.